# JAVA передать значение из консоли в метод

Tags: java

Добрый день,
 метод cls.read() получает из консоли значения переменных first и second. Как можно передать значения этих переменных в следующий метод cost()? Если выполнить текущий код то cost выведет 0. Спасибо большое за ответ.

```
package lab2oop;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2oop {
    int first;
    double second;

     void read() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите переменную First: ");
        Integer first = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Введите переменную Double: ");
        Double second = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(second);
    }
    void cost() {
        double Total = first*second;
        System.out.println(Total);
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lab2oop cls = new Lab2oop();
//        cls.init();
        cls.read();
        cls.cost();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зачем-то в методе `read()` заводите две новые одноименные полям класса переменные `first` и `second`, которые, как я понял, хотите в дальнейшем использовать в методе этого же класса `cost()`.

Можете решить эту проблему, например, так:

```
void read() {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Введите переменную First: ");
   first = in.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Введите переменную Double: ");
   second = in.nextDouble();
   System.out.println(first);
   System.out.println(second);
}
```

Comment: воу! работает) спасибо! Только начинаю разбираться в java и вот такие косяки делаю:(